# Distance from point to plane in a cube

Tags: geometry

Given $ABCD.EFGH$ cube with side length is $a$ cm. Find the length of

1. $F$ to $BEG$
2. $F$ to $ABGE$

I tried to make projection of $BEG$ from $G$ to middle of $BE$, but I don't how to do the next because the $F$ point position is like the top/bottom of the $BEG$ plane so my logic is stuck here.

I need your help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

we can solve such kind of problems using coordinates.
Let the cube :
$$
A=(0,0,0) \quad B=(a,0,0) \quad C=(a,a,0) \quad D=(0,a,0)
$$
$$
E=(0,0,a) \quad F=(a,0,a) \quad G=(a,a,a) \quad H=(0,a,a)
$$
Now we can find any distance using the formulas of analytic geometry.

As an example, for your question 1. :

the first step is to find the equation of the plane passing thorough $BEG$.

Use $BE=(-a,0,a)$ and $BG=(0,a,a)$ as vectors on the plane and find the orthogonal vector $\vec n= BE \times BG= (a^2,a^2,a^2)$, so the equation of the plane orthogonal to this vector and passing thorough $B$ is $(a^2,a^2,a^2) \cdot(x-a,y,z)=0$ i.e. 
$$
a^2x+a^2y+a^2z-a^3=0
$$
and the distance of $F$ from this plane is:
$$
d=\dfrac{a^3+a^3-a^3}{\sqrt{a^4+a^4+a^4}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt 3}
$$
(see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html) )

In the same way you can find the answer to the second question.

Comment: Truly awesome! I've never thought find distance by using vector. I usually need to draw many lines in the cube and use many properties (Phytagoras, congruence, etc.) to solve them. Thanks!

Comment: How come $BE \cdot BG$ is $(a^2,a^2,a^2)$?

Comment: It is $BE \times BG$ : the cross product, not the dot product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: @Emilio Novati Im curious, does basic geometry application (like pythagoras,3D trigonometry,congruence,etc) for 3D isn't taught much in western country ? because i've only seen people use vector meanwhile people in my country only use basic geometry to solve 3D problem (distance and angles) inside simple 3D figures, maybe it's already forgotten ?